# how to catch http fails on post requests

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

In my service i'm calling API this way:

```js
async check_initial_cpf(cpf:string){
    return this.http.post(environment.api_url+'/check_initial_cpf', {}, {cpf:cpf}).toPromise();
}
```

So in my page I'm calling the service this way:

```js
const check_cpf = await this.cnhService.check_initial_cpf(this.form_cpf);

if(check_cpf['error'] == true){
    presentAlertError();
} else {
    console.log('it worked');
}
```

This is working to catch `HTTP 200` with content `{'error':'api error message'}`

But nothing happens when HTTP request fails for other reasons (like 404, 500, etc).

How can I do this in a clean way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap this inside a `try`/`catch` block. You'd probably get errors in the `catch` block in that case:

```
try {
  const check_cpf = await this.cnhService.check_initial_cpf(this.form_cpf);
  if (check_cpf['error'] == true) {
    presentAlertError();
  } else {
    console.log('it worked');
  }
} catch(error) {
  presentAlertError();
}
```

### UPDATE

Since you're using `HttpClient` to make the API Call, it doesn't make sense to first convert the `Observable` into a promise and then catch the error in the `catch` block.

You could catch the error using [**`catchError`**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html) and then throw it back to the caller using [**`throwError`**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/throw.html). That way, you would be able to catch it in the second callback that you supply to the `subscribe` method.

Something like this:

```
check_initial_cpfObservable(something) {
  return this.http
    .get("your-url-here")
    .pipe(catchError(error => throwError(error)));
}
```

And then in the component:

```
this.cnhService.check_initial_cpfObservable(this.form_cpf)
  .subscribe(
    response => console.log('It Worked in Observable!'),
    error => this.presentAlertError()
  )
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Code Sample Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-error-handling-using-catch-error-and-throw-error) for your ref with both the approaches.

Answer (score 1):

I personally will handle the error in the observable using the [catchError](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/catchError) operator:

```js
  async check_initial_cpf(cpf: string) {
    return this.http
      .post(environment.api_url + "/check_initial_cpf", {}, { cpf: cpf })
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError()))
      .toPromise();
  }

  private handleError<T>() {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
      console.error(error); // log to console or do something with you error

      // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
      // Or you can return a custom error observable
      return EMPTY;
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

So if you want to catch en error in the request one example could be:

```
this.http.post(environment.api_url+'/check_initial_cpf', {}, {cpf:cpf}).toPromise().catch(err=>{
  console.error(err)
});
```

In the catch method you can handle the different errors.
More information: https://angular.io/guide/http#error-handling or https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html

Answer (score 1):

Your service return an observable (or must do this). And în your component you can handle the error so:

```
await this.cnhService.check_initial_cpf(this.form_cpf).subscribe(result => {
// do something with your result (status Code 2xx)
}, err => {
// handle error,
// example: console.log(err.message);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I need to say that it's a shame not to take advantage of reactive Observables, but that's your choice.

Now concerning your problème: when you use await for synchronous behavior, you need to wrap your call with a classic try catch bloc, in order to handle promise rejections.

I Hope it helped you a bit.